# Problem in finding all prime factors of a number in prolog

Tags: prolog, primes, prime-factoring

I have written the following prolog code to find all the prime factors of a number.

```
find_factors(0).
find_factors(N):- N>0, isPrime(N), write(N),nl, S is N-1, find_factors(S).
```

where the predicate isPrime(N) checks whether a number is prime or not and returns true or false accordingly.
However with my logic, I always get false as output. Where is the problem?? I am very new to prolog programming, so I am struggling a little bit.

If further clarifications needed, drop a comment below.

Comment: If the starting number is not 0 nor prime your procedure will directly fail, and if it's prime it will fail upon recursion as if X is prime then X-1 is not prime for X>3 . I'd also suggest you review your algorithm (in paper) or search for a factorization algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should not start with prime factorization to learn Prolog, because your code does not suggest you have a clear idea of that problem. I have a hard time interpreting the intention/idea behind your code.

I recommend to start learning prolog by picking a problem that you already understand.

Then maybe start thinking about how a suitable predicate for your solution should look like.

In the case of prime factorization, it could be maybe
`prime_factors(N, List)`, which is supposed to be provable if `N` is a number and `List` is the list of all of its prime factors.
Or it could be
`prime_factor(N, F)`, which is supposed to be provable if `N` is a number and `F` is one of its prime factors.

In other words: what questions do you want to ask the prolog system?